# Submit posts from users without wordpress panel

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

I want to create a system that users can submit posts .
For that , i changed the users role to the contributor .
And it's perfect , users can submit the posts .
But i don't like to users can access the wordpress panel .
I want to users submit their posts from custom user profile in theme .
Is there any function or trick that i do it ?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71382/add-custom-post-type-items-from-frontend try like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this:
**Method 1:**

```
There are certain plugins that you can use to accomplish the task. 
The below is an example:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/screenshots/
```

**Method 2:**

```
You too can achieve this functionality by writing a piece of code that will insert the data in the posts table. for that you have to create a page template and create a form for that template and write code that will work on submit of the form.
Make sure the form data gets inserted into the posts table.
```

Comment: Okay so here are the steps:
1: Create a form page template, with the desired fields.
2: on clicking the submit button try to call wp_insert_post in function.php. The below link best describes how to insert the post using wp_insert_post:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/.